# Core Bluetooth scanForPeripheralsWithServiced:Options and stopScan methods cost and efficient use

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a **CBCentralManager** where **CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey**
 is included when scanning for peripherals for the purpose of getting live **RSSI** feedback from them. I am doing this to detect their presence and their proximity to the central in real time.

The problem is, when the app is in background mode, this scanning option is not allowed (**restricted**). Therefore, the only option I'm seeing is running an interval where the scanner is started,followed by timer, then stop the scanner (example: one second "on" three seconds "off" or maybe much less for both). I am wondering whether this approach is inefficient (large overhead, long delay,...) or even erroneous?

Comment: I don't think you can use this approach in the background because your app cannot execute continually in the background and timers do not fire

Comment: @Paulw11 So any suggestions?

Comment: Use iBeacons?  You can range them in the background. I don't believe there is any way to do what you want in the background for generic BLE devices

Comment: I just noticed you have tagged OS X as well as iOS. My comments refer to iOS only. OS X has no restrictions on "background"

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks!. Since CB works in the background mode, my purpose of trying to do what I essentially asked about is to let CBCentralManager forget about discovered CBPeripherals. I need to do that so that whenever a peripheral re-enters the centrals range it gets discovered (or rediscovered in this case). I don't necessarily want catch all the peripheral's advertising packets. Just recognizing re-entry.

Comment: Restarting the scanning lets CBCentralManager forget about it's already discovered peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was able to put two  methods (stop followed by scan) within didDicoverPeripheral central's delegate method, this made the program (app) behave as if it is discovering then forgetting the peripheral in BG mode, which mimics the one with CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey when in foreground. Is doing this considered a bad practice? do you think continual immediate restarting of the scanner causes bad effects?

Comment: It will drain the battery faster